# App stops responding on multiple geocoder requests

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-geocoder

The app stops responding for a while and then come back to normal with all the markers. The app hangs even for a list with size 30. Here is my code,

```
private void addMarkersByPlace(List<JSONObject> data_arr){
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < data_arr.size(); i++) {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(data_arr.get(i).getString("position"), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                LatLng position = new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude()+(Math.random()/200),addresses.get(0).getLongitude()+(Math.random()/200));
                Bitmap bmImg = Ion.with(this).load(data_arr.get(i).getString("icon")).asBitmap().get();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(position)
                        .title(data_arr.get(i).getString("title"))
                        .snippet(data_arr.get(i).getString("snippet"))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImg))
                );
            }
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        txt_msg.setText("ERROR : "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main thread does too much work, and this may cause an ANR.

Create an AsyncTask ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) that queries the geocoder and draw the `Markers` on the `onPostExecute` method (the markers must be drawn on the main thread).

Your `AsyncTask` can be like this (not tested):

```
private class QueryGeocoder extends AsyncTask<List<JSONObject>, Integer, List<Address>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(List<JSONObject>... objects) {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for (JSONObject object : objects) {
                addresses.add(geoCoder.getFromLocationName(object.getString("position"), 1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }

        return addresses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> result) {
        for (Address address : result) {
            LatLng position = new LatLng(address.getLatitude()+(Math.random()/200),address.getLongitude()+(Math.random()/200));
            Bitmap bmImg = Ion.with(this).load(address.getString("icon")).asBitmap().get();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(position)
                            .title(address.getString("title"))
                            .snippet(address.getString("snippet"))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImg))
            );                
        }
    }
}
```

You can execute it like this:

```
new QueryGeocoder().execute(data_arr);
```